# Ajax pagination in Symfony 1.4

Tags: ajax, symfony1

I am using symfony 1.4 and am trying to paginate my search results using Ajax calls but am having difficulties.

My ajax call is made to an action (executeGetList) where I pass in the page parameter. This is how I make the ajax call:

```
var url = "<?php echo url_for("genre/getList"); ?>";
function loadPage(page)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: url+"?page="+page,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        timeout: 4000,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loading').show();
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#loading').hide();
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            msg = "Error " + errorThrown;
            alert(msg);
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#datasongs").load(data, "", function(response, status, xhr) {
                alert ("status is: " + status); 
            });
        }
    });
}
```

`executeGetList` retrieves some data, sets up the pager (sfDoctrinePager) and return a renderpartial like:

```
return $this->renderPartial('song/listSongSearchLite', 
                            array('roster' => $this->roster, 
                            'pagerSongs' => $this->pagerSongs));
```

In the ajax call's `success` call back function, I retrieve the data sent and it is exactly what I want. However, when I perform the `.load()` jquery function, I get a 404 error.

The error is caused because symfony is trying to find a route which starts with the html generated by the ajax call. The data returned starts with

```
<table><thead><tr
```

The symfony logs are:

```
Oct 28 23:32:05 symfony [info] {sfWebResponse} Send status "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
Oct 28 23:32:05 symfony [info] {sfWebResponse} Send header "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
Oct 28 23:32:05 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} Configuration 12.69 ms (8)
Oct 28 23:32:05 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} Factories 58.78 ms (1)
Oct 28 23:32:05 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} Action "genre/getList" 705.05 ms (1)
Oct 28 23:32:05 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} Database (Doctrine) 0.18 ms (24)
Oct 28 23:32:05 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} Partial "song/_listSongSearchLite" 222.21 ms (1)
Oct 28 23:32:05 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} View "None" for "genre/getList" 0.02 ms (1)
Oct 28 23:32:05 symfony [info] {sfWebResponse} Send content (8801 o)
Oct 28 23:32:07 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Connect sfRoute "sf_guard_signin" (/guard/login)
Oct 28 23:32:07 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Connect sfRoute "sf_guard_signout" (/guard/logout)
Oct 28 23:32:07 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Connect sfRoute "apply" (/user/new)
Oct 28 23:32:07 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Connect sfRoute "reset" (/user/password-reset)
Oct 28 23:32:07 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Connect sfRoute "resetRequest" (/user/reset-request)
Oct 28 23:32:07 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Connect sfRoute "resetCancel" (/user/reset-cancel)
Oct 28 23:32:07 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Connect sfRoute "validate" (/user/confirm/:validate)
Oct 28 23:32:07 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Connect sfRoute "settings" (/user/settings)
Oct 28 23:32:07 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Match route "default_index" (/:module) for /<table><thead><tr with parameters array (  'module' => '<table><thead><tr',  'action' => 'index',)
Oct 28 23:32:08 symfony [info] {sfFrontWebController} Action "tabletheadtr/index" does not exist
Oct 28 23:32:08 symfony [err] {sfError404Exception} Action "tabletheadtr/index" does not exist.
Oct 28 23:32:08 symfony [info] {sfWebResponse} Send status "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"
Oct 28 23:32:08 symfony [info] {sfWebResponse} Send header "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
Oct 28 23:32:08 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} Configuration 8.27 ms (5)
Oct 28 23:32:08 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} Factories 63.62 ms (1)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Mohit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you have:

```
success: function(data){
$("#datasongs").load(data, "", function(response, status, xhr) {
   alert ("status is: " + status);  
});
```

where you pass the data returned from the `.ajax()` as the url for the new request `.load()`. Doesn't seem right.

```
.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )
```

It seems like you are trying to put the data returned inside `$("#datasongs")`. For that you use the function `.html()` not `.load()`.

Comment: Thanks Samura, this seems to have done the job. However, when the container is 'refreshed' with new data, the window automatically scrolls to the top of the page. Do you know how to keep it in the same position?

Comment: If you use a `<a onclick="">` to trigger the ajax, try `return false` on that like: `<a onclick="loadPage(); return false;">`